# Djangochannelsrestframework doesn't work like in documentation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to create websocket connection with djangochannelsrestframework. I tried all like in documentation and I got this error
"django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

https://djangochannelsrestframework.readthedocs.io/

My Traceback is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/venv/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 170, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 232, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/./igroteka/asgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    import socketapp.routing
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/./socketapp/routing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from socketapp import consumers
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/./socketapp/consumers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from games.models import Games
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/./games/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    class GamesCategories(models.Model):
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 127, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/user/Projects/igroteka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
Sentry is attempting to send 2 pending error messages
Waiting up to 2 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

This is my github repository to chek code
https://github.com/muradoff101/igroteka/tree/master

Comment: Please post the full error traceback

Answer (score 0):

If your consumers import your models then you need to call `get_asgi_application()` in `asgi.py` before importing your routing, otherwise Django throws the error when a model is created before Django is initialised

asgi.py:

```
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'igroteka.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application() # Call this before importing routing

import socketapp.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            socketapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: The error dissappeared this answer, but the websocket connection still not working

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/' failed:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed channels version 4 which is the latest, default one, and this does not start the ASGI server in development mode. please verify this and install channels version == 3.0.5 . do verify ASGI server starts when you run the runserver command.

( Version 4 supports ASGI server via daphne, I guess so, not tried.)